# Rails 4 reloading code in lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know, this question was asked at least milion times, but I still can't find the right solution. I mean clean and easy, like it is supposed to be in Rails applications.

Let's imagine I am developer of an application that needs some code in the lib folder. My app's name is Xy. I will create a file xy.rb in the lib folder with this content:

```
require 'xy/version'
module Xy
end
```

After that I will create next file in `lib/xy/` named `version.rb`:

```
module Xy
  module VERSION
    def self.to_s
       "1.0.0"
    end
  end
end
```

So far, so good. Then I will create some controller and I will edit routes:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render text: Xy::VERSION
  end
end

root 'index#index'
```

I also need require my code, in application.rb I will add `require 'xy'`

Then I will run my server `rails s` and I will wisit the app in the browser `http://localhost:3000` - seems good, I see 1.0.0.

Then I will update the version string in `Xy::VERSION` to `1.0.1` and I'll refresh the browser - here it comes, I will no see the change. To see it I will have to restart the server. And this is quite anoying.

So the question is: What is the right way to force RoR 4+ to reload changes in the lib folder in development environment?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

I'm using this in my app now, you never need to even require' the lib files anywhere and don't have to restart the server. Just make sure you name your files correctly. E.g

/lib/foo/rb

```
class Foo
```

/lib/foo/bar.rb

```
class Foo::Bar
```

Comment: This is good, but you must not have any require in your lib source code. For example this: `require 'xy/version'` in your `lib/xy.rb` will cause that `VERSION` is not reloaded.